# How do I cap number of rows in based on category using postgres policies?

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security, supabase

I have a database of `orders` and each order has a `time_slot` (of type `TIME`).

```sql
select id, time_slot from orders limit 5;

 10 | 13:00:00
 11 | 12:00:00
 13 | 11:00:00
 14 | 12:30:00
 15 | 11:30:00
```

I want to make sure that only a certain number of orders can be placed in a time slot; for example, let's say I only want 8 orders per time slot.

I am using Supabase, so I would like to implement using RLS policies.

I've been through several iterations, but none of them have worked. Some complain of infinite recursion. My current approach is the following: I have created a view of time slot load.

```sql
create or replace view time_slot_load as 
  select time_slot, count(*) 
  from orders
  group by time_slot;
select * from time_slot_load limit 5;

 11:00:00  |     1
 12:30:00  |     1
 11:30:00  |     1
 13:00:00  |     1
 12:00:00  |     7
```

I can then create a policy that checks against this view.

```sql
ALTER POLICY "Only 8 orders per time slot"
  ON public.orders
  WITH CHECK (
    (SELECT (load.count <= 8)
       FROM time_slot_load load
       WHERE (load.time_slot = orders.time_slot))
    );
```

But this is not working.

Is there some way I can do this using constraints or RLS policies?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a job for a trigger, not for an RLS policy.

Comment: use trigger would be easier.  time_slot  should be range type.

Answer (score 0):

[**demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=403346c743cff1009f74226731e3095c)

table structure:

begin;

```
create table orders_count(
    time_slot tstzrange ,
    order_count integer default 0,
     constraint order_ct_max1000 check(order_count <=4));
create table 
    orders(orderid int primary key, realtimestamp timestamptz , order_info text);

with a as(
SELECT x as begin_,x + interval '1 hour' as end_
FROM   generate_series(
    timestamp '2022-01-01',
    timestamp '2022-01-02',
    interval  '60 min') t(x))
insert into orders_count(time_slot)  
       select tstzrange(a.begin_, a.end_,'[]') from a;
commit;
```

two table, one table for all the orders info, another table is track the timeslot's count, also make one constraint, within one timeslot no more than 4 orderid.
Then create trigger for delete/update/insert action on table orders.
for table orders_count, 20 years only 175200 rows (one hour one row).

main trigger function:

```
begin;
create or replace function f_trigger_orders_in()
returns trigger as
$$
begin
update orders_count set  order_count =  order_count + 1
where time_slot @> NEW.realtimestamp;
return null;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create or replace function f_trigger_orders_up()
returns trigger as
$$
begin
if OLD.realtimestamp <> NEW.realtimestamp THEN
update orders_count
set order_count = order_count -1
where time_slot @> OLD.realtimestamp;

update orders_count
set order_count  = order_count + 1
where time_slot @> NEW.realtimestamp;
end if;
return null;
end
$$ language plpgsql;

create or replace function f_trigger_order_delaft()
returns trigger as
$$
BEGIN
update orders_count set order_count = order_count -1 where time_slot  @> OLD.realtimestamp;
return  null;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

triggers action:

```
create trigger trigger_in_orders 
    AFTER INSERT ON public.orders FOR EACH ROW execute procedure f_trigger_orders_in();
create trigger trigger_up_orders 
    after update on public.orders for each row execute procedure f_trigger_orders_up();
create trigger trigger_del_orders 
    AFTER DELETE ON public.orders  FOR EACH ROW execute procedure f_trigger_order_delaft();
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make sure that only a certain number of orders can be placed
> in a time slot; for example, let's say I only want 8 orders per time
> slot.

You cannot do that in PostgreSQL.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createpolicy.html

check_expression:

> Any SQL conditional expression (returning boolean). The conditional
> expression cannot contain any **aggregate** or **window functions**. This
> expression will be used in INSERT and UPDATE queries against the table
> if row-level security is enabled. Only rows for which the expression
> evaluates to true will be allowed. An error will be thrown if the
> expression evaluates to false or null for any of the records inserted
> or any of the records that result from the update. Note that the
> check_expression is evaluated against the proposed new contents of the
> row, not the original contents.

Why view won't work:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html
see **Updatable Views** section:

> A view is automatically updatable if it satisfies all of the following
> conditions:
>
> - The view's select list must not contain any aggregates, window functions or set-returning functions.